# How to have a bold header text?

Tags: html, css, header, footer, bold

I can't find out how to give my header text some  (bold) [like on this design](http://forrst.com/posts/zmL/original).

[Here is my html/css project](http://sijdesign.dk/test/).

There is something wrong with my footer too, I can't give it margin-top or margin-botton :/

I hope someone can give me some tips and tell me what I can do better :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the bold, remove the

```
<b>TEXT</b>
```

tags and use

```
<span style='font-weight: bold;'>TEXT</span>
```

For the margin, try padding, OR add this before the FOOTER tag

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For bold text, I prefer to make a boldText class which can be applied to pretty much anything without having to re-declare the style inline:
    .boldText {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

```
<element class="boldText">...</element>
```

That way your "element" could be a span, p, or entire div if you wanted to.

As for the footer margin issue; I just took a look at your site and I'm not seeing anything that looks like an "issue."  Did you figure that part out already?

Comment: ye clear: both; worked like Stew said, and i have just <span class="bold">Bold text here</span> :) thanks for help